# General Lower Bound of Power in Neyman-Pearson

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-power, decision-theory, neyman-pearson-lemma

Let $X$ be an $\sigma$-finite space $(\mathcal{X}, F_{\mathcal{X}}, \nu)$ valued absolutely continuous random variable whose distribution is one of $P_0 = f_0(x)d\nu(x)$ or $P_1 = f_1(x)d\nu(x)$. We test the null hypothesis who says that $X$ has distribution $P_0$ against the alternative hypothesis who says that $X$ has distribution $P_1$. Given size $\alpha \in (0,1)$, the Neyman-Pearson lemma shows that the uniformly most powerful test $T : \mathcal{X} \to [0,1]$ representing rejection probability (more precisely, if we use randomised rule $\delta$ over the two decisions, $T(x) = \delta (x, \{1\})$ is that:

\begin{equation*}
T(X) = \begin{cases}
1  & f_1(X) > c f_0(X)\\
\gamma & f_1(X) = c f_0(X) \\
0 & f_1(X) < c f_0(X)
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Here $\gamma \in [0,1]$ and $c \in [0, \infty]$ are known constants chosen so that the size is $\alpha$. Typically, we choose them in the following way. Put, for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$ :

\begin{equation*}
\gamma(t) = P_{0} \{ f_1 > t f_0\} = P_0 (\{x \in \mathcal{X} \mid f_1(x) > t f_0(x)\})
\end{equation*}

Choose $c$ such that $\gamma(c) \leqslant \alpha \leqslant \gamma(c-)$. If $\gamma(c-) = \gamma(c)$, put $\gamma = 0$. Otherwise, put $\gamma = \frac{\alpha - \gamma(c)}{\gamma(c-)-\gamma(c)}$. This assures $\mathbb{E}_0[T(X)]=\alpha$.

I know that $T$ constructed in this way has its power always strictly greater than $\alpha$ (That is, $\mathbb{E}_1[T(X)] > \mathbb{E}_0[T(X)] = \alpha$. ) unless $P_0=P_1$ . But this lower bound is too weak. Is there any general lower bound on power $\mathbb{E}_1[T(X)]$ else than the one I mentionned?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can come up with a tighter bound.

For example, if you have a sample $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n \sim \mathrm{N}(\mu,1)$ and you're testing $H_0:\mu=\mu_0$ versus $H_1:\mu=\mu_1$, you can easily see that the power of the MPT converges to $\alpha$ as $\mu_1$ approaches $\mu_0$.